# Matplotlib: Hide Y and X values on a plot audio graph with tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I know this may be a duplicated question, but for my issue in particular I haven't been able solve it with solutions that I found online.

I have this audio plot graph I made with tkinter and matplotlib but after trying looking at their documentation and other sites online I haven't been able to remove the values on the axis.

This is what currently looks like

[image]

and this is what I would want it to look like

[image]

```
rate, data = scipy.io.wavfile.read(filename)
plt.plot(data)
fig = Figure(figsize=(6, 3), dpi=45)
fig.add_subplot(111).plot(data, color="#035be3")
fig.set_facecolor('#1d1d1d')
fig.set_alpha(1)
ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_yticklabels([])
ax.set_xticklabels([])
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x=20, y=250)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plt.axes()` is creating a new Axes instance, so when you `set_xticklabels` and `set_yticklabels` it is not acting on the axes you want. You also `plt.plot` before you create the figure. You might consider reordering your code to create the figure and axes first, then doing the plotting and modifications to the labels on the object you create first. For example:

```
rate, data = scipy.io.wavfile.read(filename)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 3), dpi=45)

fig.set_facecolor('#1d1d1d')
fig.set_alpha(1)

ax.plot(data, color="#035be3")
ax.set_yticklabels([])
ax.set_xticklabels([])

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().place(x=20, y=250)
```